# Using 'params' keyword to include single values as well as a value collection

Tags: c#

I know the title of the question isn't very clear, but let me try to explain as best as I can.

I'm working on an application that modifies bytes of a file. I have two classes for this: `Mod` and `Action`.

An `Action` is stored in an instance of `Mod`, this tells the application which bytes to modify at which specific address:

```
public class Action
{
    public Action(int address, params byte[] bytes)
    {
        Address = address;
        Bytes = bytes;
    }

    public int Address { get; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; }
}
public class Mod
{
    public Mod(string name, List<Action> actions)
    {
        Name = name;
        Actions = actions;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Action> Actions { get; }
}
```

Now, there are some bytes that I wish to write, which become rather repetitive, so instead of assigning them to `bytes` when creating an instance of `Action`, I have stored said byte array inside a static class called `OpCodes`:

```
public static class OpCodes
{
    public static byte[] BX_LR = {0x70, 0x47};
}
```

So now what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
new Action(0x1AF0F0, 0x01, 0x20, OpCodes.BX_LR) //Return 1. (true)
```

As you can see, I want to use bytes `0x01`, `0x20` and then I also want to use the value of `BX_LR`, however, the compiler doesn't like that.

I get this:

> Argument 4: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'byte'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: compiler doesn't like that?

Comment: I added what the compiler says.

Comment: There's already an `Action` class in the framework. You may want to change that, but it's not necessary!

Comment: add 0x01, 0x20 to byte array and then pass

Comment: `new Action(0x1AF0F0, (new[] { 0x01, 0x20 }).Concat(OpCodes.BX_LR).ToArray())`?

Comment: @MattBurland I suppose that could work, but it looks rather ugly. At that point, I may as well just do `new Action(0x1AF0F0, 0x01, 0x20, 0x70, 0x47);`

Comment: Yes, it does look kind of ugly. Your best bet might be to have each of those terms in your `BX_LR` as separate constants, for example `public const byte BX = 0x70; public const byte LR = 0x47`. Then your call just becomes: `new Action(0x1AF0F0, 0x01, 0x20, OpCodes.BX, OpCodes.LR);` which is easier to read and you won't accidentally use the mistype the code for `BX` or `LR` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I conjuted this in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Action(0x1AF0F0, 0x01, 0x20, OpCode.BX_LR); //Return 1. (true)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

public class Action
{
    public Action(int address, params OpCode[] bytes)
    {
        Address = address;
        Bytes = OpCode.Flatten(bytes);
    }

    public int Address { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}

public class Mod
{
    public Mod(string name, List<Action> actions)
    {
        Name = name;
        Actions = actions;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class OpCode
{
    private byte[] _value;

    private OpCode(byte[] value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static byte[] BX_LR = {0x70, 0x47};

    public static implicit operator OpCode (byte value)
    {
        return new OpCode(new []{value});
    }

    public static implicit operator OpCode (byte[] value)
    {
        return new OpCode(value);
    }

    public static byte[] Flatten (OpCode[] opCodes)
    {
        var result = new List<byte>(opCodes.Length);
        foreach (var opCode in opCodes)
        {
            result.AddRange(opCode._value);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The output in LinqPad is as follows:

```
Address
1765616 
Bytes
01 20 70 47
```

---

The code is using the class `OpCode` (I renamed `OpCodes` to singular) as intermediary between `byte[]` and `byte`. It makes for nice invocation.

The idea is that the constructor of `Action` takes a `params` of `OpCode` and any `byte` or `byte[]` will implicitly be casted to `OpCode` so you can just put bytes in the call... then in the constructure you can flat the structure to a single `byte[]` with a dedicated call.

Note: I added `set;` to the properties because of LinqPad's complains.

---

The benefits or this are in readability of the call, yet as you can see there is an overhead... that overhead will only make sense for long series of bytes.

Btw. you can make `_value` readonly, I would also suggest to make `OpCode` <strike>`sealed`</strike> a `struct`. The reason is that using `OpCode` as presented in the code will be created a bunch of short lived objects, but if they are `struct` then they will not load the garbage collector. Also, don't allow for derivec types. Edit: drawback of the struct is that you can't control the default constructor, and that will initilize it with `_values` as `null`.

Another suggestion si to define the public static fields as `readonly` (don't allow to replace them) and `OpCode`, that will save a cast and will prevent tampering the array.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne one more thing, this will be creating a bunch of short lived objects. The .NET garbage collector is good on that, yet if it ever becomes a problem, you can keep an array with the 256 single byte `OpCodes` and implement the implicit cast by array lookup. Edit: it just ocurred to me that using struct will solve that much better.

Comment: Up-voted for using implicit type casting, something not seen very often.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an extension method to prepend/append those bytes to an array:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static byte[] Prepend(this byte[] that, params byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] modified;

        modified = new byte[that.Length + data.Length];
        Array.Copy(data, modified, data.Length);
        Array.Copy(that, 0, modified, data.Length, that.Length);

        return modified;
    }

    public static byte[] Append(this byte[] that, params byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] modified;

        modified = new byte[that.Length + data.Length];
        Array.Copy(that, modified, that.Length);
        Array.Copy(data, 0, modified, that.Length, data.Length);

        return modified;
    }
}
```

You can now use them like this:

```
new Action(0x1AF0F0, OpCodes.BX_LR.Prepend(0x01, 0x20))
```

Or this:

```
new Action(0x1AF0F0, OpCodes.BX_LR.Append(0x01, 0x20))
```